# Changing Edit-text status to password programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext

I have a textbox in my application and as the picture below shows,

by clicking on show-checkbox the pin edittext type must be changed to password
and any existing character in the box must be transformed to *.

[image]

I know we can use xml to define password edittext but as I explained, I need to changed the edittext type programmatically.

I couldn't find any keyword for textbox to change its type to password, any advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Store the text of EditText in some temporary variable using

```
String temporary_stored_text = mEditText.getText().toString.trim();
```

and then on selection of the Show checkbox change the input type of EditText from Normal to password type using

```
mEditText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

and refill the EditText with the temporary stored value of EditText using

```
mEditText.setText(temporary_stored_text);
```

To get it back to normal do nothing,

```
mEditText.setTransformationMode(null);
```

and get the Text.

Comment: its working but it's setTransformationMethod(null); not Mode. 
I don't know how did you come up with this alien solution... ;) you're genius. thx

Comment: Actually setting it to null means not setting any mode - NORMAL MODE. :)